# How do Neo4j OGMs reliably work upon nodes/relationships?

Tags: neo4j, language-agnostic

Neo4j node/relationship IDs are of a dynamic nature and from what I can tell after having read the documentation and various articles online, they can be reused.

So, for example, say, I have an operation O1 operating on `(x)`, which has an ID of 100. Another operation O2 may delete `(x)` and create `(y)` (while O1 is blocked, for example, due to an I/O operation), and coincidentally, `(y)` may also turn out to have a node ID of 100. When O1 resumes execution, and tries to modify the node presumed to be `(x)` (but now actually `(y)`, but O1 can't tell because it has the same node ID), we'd have all sorts of bad data for that node.

Having worked with a certain number of OGMs (all written in PHP, although I suspect that the same would apply of OGMs in other languages too), what I can see is that all of them rely upon the ID, which may often have dangerous consequences, as described above.

How does Neo4j OGMs handle these cases? Or is the above case "rare enough" (with the same probability of, say, two UUIDs colliding) so as not to be a reason for concern?

Answer (score 0):

I primarily know of two OGMs:

- [neo4j-ogm](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm) for Java
- The [neo4j](https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j) Ruby gem (which I am one of the maintainers of)

I can't speak for the Java library, but on the Ruby side we generate a `uuid` property on all nodes using Ruby's [SecureRandom.uuid](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html#method-c-uuid).  This is how we uniquely identify nodes.  The user can alternatively choose to have their own "natural" key (like a US social security number).  So long as it can have a Neo4j UNIQUE constraint on it, it can be used.

In the current stable version of the gem (7.1) the constraints are created automagically.  In the upcoming major version (8.0) users will need to create these constraints themselves (there is also a new migrations system to help with this), but the gem will raise an error if there isn't a constraint for the ID property of a model.

Also, since Neo4j / Neo Tech encourages browsing Neo4j graphs starting from the perspective of nodes and not relationships, we don't store a unique ID on relationships.

Comment: How do you retrieve nodes that were created without an UUID, then? (For example, those that may have been created from the web interface without a uuid property)

Comment: You can do `Model.find_by_neo_id` for one thing, but generally you want to make sure there is a UUID on there.  We have a migration which finds any nodes which don't have UUIDs and adds them, so that helps.  Also, Ruby's `SecureRandom.uuid` is based on RFC 4122 so there should be an implementation in other languages if you're creating nodes there

Comment: (Also `Model.find_by(neo_id: 123)`, `Model.find_by(other_property: value)`, `Model.where(prop: value)`, etc...)

Comment: Note also that operations on nodes imply locking, which would prevent a thread to delete a node managed by another thread.

Comment: We use neo4j internal ids for both the java and php ogm, problems mentioned would appear also by using uuids

Comment: @ChristopheWillemsen could you expand upon that with your own answer? Is the probability of collisions as rare as that of 2 UUIDs colliding?

Comment: Neo4j is transactional, there is no probability of collision of generating an id that already exist, the only thing that could happen in case of collisions is that your transaction will fail

Comment: Another detail, we recently had some help from a community member to put in support for the Neo4j ID as an option for the `neo4j` gem's ID property, so that will be an option in 8.0